# how to calculate dynamic sum for a specific column in angular6 for a given live data

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular6

I have created a data table in angular. Now I am trying to get the sum column wise based on search filter but it is not working. I am not finding a proper solution. can anyone guide me?. Thanks in advance

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').dataTable( {
              "fnFooterCallback": function ( nRow, aaData, iDataStart, iDataEnd ) {
                /* Calculate the total market share for all browsers in this table (ie inc. outside
                 * the pagination
                 */
                var total = 0;
                for ( var i=0 ; i<aaData.length ; i++ )
                {
                  total+= aaData[i][8]*1;
                }

                /* Calculate the market share for browsers on this page */
                var value = 0;
                for ( var i=iDataStart ; i<iDataEnd ; i++ )
                {
                  value += aaData[i][8]*1;
                }

                /* Modify the footer row to match what we want */
                var nCells = nRow.getElementsByTagName('th');
                nCells[1].innerHTML = parseInt(value * 100)/100 +
                  '% ('+ parseInt(total * 100)/100 +'% total)';
              }
            } );
          } );
```

Comment: the contents of the table were printed from an array, right?

Comment: yes sir @AkberIqbal

Comment: Traverse the array and get the sum... If you need help, update the question with the array structure and dummy data and you'll get help

Comment: yes sir done,got the sum. After that when i search for some data(amount) in search field in the filters that total data  i need to get but i am not getting how can i get searched total amount data .can u tell me which method can be used for proper solution@AkberIqbal

Comment: how do you filter the results based upon the search? can you provide a minimal stackblitz?

Comment: by using data tables. search field is filtered automatically@AkberIqbal